# setPadding on ImageView doesnt work after setLayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, padding

I'm making a custom `View` thats derived from an `ImageView`and I control where the image has to be within this `ImageView` using padding.

I have set OnClickListener on my custom ImageView that resizes it:

```
image.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                image.resize_image();
            }
});
```

and this is how this function is looking like

```
public void resize_image(){
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = new_heigth;
        params.width = new_width;
        setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

After this resizing is done I don't want my displayed image to change size (only the custom ImageView is changing size so I can draw an extra stuff around this image) within my custom ImageView so inside `onDraw(Canvas)` member function I set the new padding

```
class custom_ImageView extends ImageView{
//...
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //...
        setPadding(new_left_padding, new_top_padding, new_right_padding, new_bottom_padding);
        //...
    }
//...
}
```

Result is that `width` and `heigth` are changed like I wanted but my displayed image is neither in the right position or size.

**Interesting this is that if I add an extra line of `invalidate();` in the end of my `resize_image()` and I click on my `custom_ImageView` twice - on the 2nd click image draws itself in right size and position like I wanted.**

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I kind of worked around this by not using ImageView at all but just drawing image where it needs to be by using `Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap, RectF, RectF, Paint)`

This way I don't have to specify images location using `setPadding` within `onDraw`, but I can do it simply by specifying position using `RectF`.